# How can I stop user being able to stop design view on a query in Ms Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am about to release some reports in Access 2007 and I need to lock down the Queries so that no one can change the queries does any one know how I can do this in Access 2007?

Please Note: Simply adding a GUI and hiding the "database window" is not enough as people can still get in with the right key stroke etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could [Make an .ACCDE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136539(office.12).aspx#Access2007BuildingRuntimeBasedSolutions_HelpingtoProtectYourCodewithACCDEFiles), and give that to your users to execute.

> You can create an .accde file from an
>   .accdb file by clicking Database Tools
>   on the Office Fluent Ribbon, and then
>   clicking Make ACCDE. When you create
>   an .accde file, Access compiles all
>   the code in the database and strips
>   the editable version of the code from
>   the new .accde file. This process both
>   reduces the size of the resulting
>   database and guarantees that no one
>   can change the original source code.
>   When you open an .accde file in
>   Access, the form and report designers
>   and the Visual Basic Editor are not
>   available. In addition, you cannot
>   transfer forms, reports, and modules
>   to another database by export or
>   import.

However, *since an ACCDE is apparently less secure than its predecessor the MDE,* your best bet might be to convert the database to Access 2003 format by using the *Save As* command, and making an MDE from that. If you open an older .mdb file in Access 2007, a *Make MDE* command appears on the Database Tools tab instead of the Make ACCDE command that appears when you are working in an Access 2007 database.

Comment: Thanks for you answer however if you look you can Show the Design view for the Queries and these are the very things I need protected. All the IP is in the Queries

Comment: How is an ACCDE less secure than an MDE?

Comment: MDE or ACCDE has no effect on the accessibility/editability of the queries. Those are Jet/ACE objects, not part of the VBA project and are left entirely unchanged by compiling to MDE/ACCDE. The only way your suggestion would secure them is if they are created in code on the fly each time they are needed, then deleted afterwards. In that case, for the most part, there would be no reason to persist them as saved QueryDefs in the first place, so that would solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Access, if you click the Windows button and then Access Options, then Current Database, you will see options to disable navigation and keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Sorry, but that will not stop a serious attempt at getting to the queries. Looks like it cannot be done.